# Will c# compiler optimize empty if blocks

Tags: c#, compiler-optimization

Is there a chance that C# will optimize the following code block?

```
if (specField == null || AddSystemType(specField, layout) 
                      || AddEnumType(specField, layout)
                      || AddUserType(specField, layout))
{
}
```

Comment: Build the code and then find out using ILDASM :-P

Comment: Frankly I have no idea what you mean. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: I would have thought not. The methods could have side effects.

Comment: Intersting question, bu how should it be optimized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you can use ildasm to see what the compiler has optimized for yourself. But if you were expecting it to remove the code entirely, it can't - because those three method calls could throw exceptions or modify state. So the best it could do would be to emit the equivalent of:

```
if (specField != null)
{
    if (!AddSystemType(specField, layout))
    {
        if (!AddEnumType(specField, layout))
        {
            AddUserType(specField, layout);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example is not equal to  cond || cond.
You could use && and the short circuit evalution will prevent the execution of the second condition

Answer (score 0):

The AddSystemType will execute and could change some states, so everything in the IF will be executed.

When using AND

```
if(specField == null && AddSystemType()) {

}
```

Then if specField is (always) null,  AddSystemType() isn't executed and skipped (short circuit evaluation)